# Как обработать событие - входящий звонок?

Tags: android

Как в Android обработать событие - входящий звонок?

Comment: Android Studio - IDE - программа для написания кода, она не принимает звонки, соответственно ответ на ваш вопрос - никак. Скорее всего вы хотели узнать, как получить событие входящего звонка в программе для Android? То в какой IDE вы будете писать свою программу приема звонков не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу тогда.